# monero was not received into my MyMonero wallet

Tags: mymonero, cryptopia

I have sent monero from Cryptopia to MyMonero.com, but after 24 hours, the monero was not received into my MyMonero wallet. At Cryptopia, it notes the transaction is completed, so I can't cancel the transaction from there. I ended up losing the money. Does anyone have idea to recover?

Comment: Use that guide ^. If the transaction isn't present in the blockchain, it's an issue on Cryptopia's end and you should contact their support.

Comment: @dEBRUYNE You should be a moderator ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Actually many people are having the same problem at Cryptopia while trying to withdraw their XMR, and there are people actuallly waiting for 9 days! Just keep away from them until the exchange resolves the issue.